# Volatile IEnlistmentNotification and TransactionScope.AsyncFlowEnabled = true

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, transactionscope

Apart from .NET 4.5.1 there is a new option on the TransactionScope which enables to use async flow. This allows to write the following client code

```
using(var txt = new TransactionScope(..., TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)
{
   await sender.SendAsync();
}
```

So far so good. But when I need to implement a volatile IEnlistmentNotification I'm struggling to do that. Let's imagine the following scenario, assumption: My underlying infrastructure is completely async from bottom to top

```
public class MessageSender : ISendMessages
{
    public async Task SendAsync(TransportMessage message, SendOptions options)
    {
        await sender.SendAsync(message);
    }
}
```

So what I want to achieve is to introduce a volatile IEnlistmentNotification like this:

```
internal class SendResourceManager : IEnlistmentNotification
{
    private readonly Func<Task> onCommit;

    public SendResourceManager(Func<Task> onCommit)
    {
        this.onCommit = onCommit;
    }

    public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
    {
        preparingEnlistment.Prepared();
    }

    public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        await this.onCommit();
        enlistment.Done();
    }

    public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        enlistment.Done();
    }

    public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        enlistment.Done();
    }
}
```

and the new sender

```
public class MessageSender : ISendMessages
{
    public async Task SendAsync(TransportMessage message, SendOptions options)
    {
        // Dirty: Let's assume Transaction.Current is never null
        Transaction.Current.EnlistVolatile(new SendResourceManager(async () => { await sender.SendAsync(message) }));
    }
}
```

Note: Of course this code doesn't compile. It would require me to declare the commit method async void. Which is aweful.

So my question is: How can I write an enlistment which can internally await an asynchronous operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as `EnlistVolatile` isn't a heavy CPU bound time consuming operation, you can create a thin `Task` based wrapper over `EnlistVolatile` using [`Task.FromResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static class TranscationExtensions
{
    public static Task EnlistVolatileAsync(this Transaction transaction, 
                                           IEnlistmentNotification 
                                           enlistmentNotification, 
                                           EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(transaction.EnlistVolatile
                                           (enlistmentNotification, 
                                            enlistmentOptions));
    }
}
```

and then consume it inside your method:

```
public class MessageSender : ISendMessages
{
    public Task SendAsync(TransportMessage message, SendOptions options)
    {
        return Transaction.Current.EnlistVolatileAsync
               (new SendResourceManager(async () => 
                                       { await sender.SendAsync(message) }));
    }
}
```

which can be awaited higher in your callstack:

```
MessageSender sender = new MessageSender();
await sender.SendAsync(message, options);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I will test it out tomorrow and flag the answer.

Comment: This now allows me to await the send async. But if for example the sender internally uses await Task.Delay(1000) that is never actually awaited and the method immediately returns. Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: I'd suggest to post a new question.

Comment: I did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376853/volatile-ienlistmentnotification-transactionscope-asyncflowenabled-true-and-c