# Volatile IEnlistmentNotification, TransactionScope.AsyncFlowEnabled = true and complex async/wait

Tags: c#, async-await, transactionscope

This is a followup question to the following question:

[Volatile IEnlistmentNotification and TransactionScope.AsyncFlowEnabled = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244154/volatile-ienlistmentnotification-and-transactionscope-asyncflowenabled-true)

The approach accepted in the question above works as long as you don't await multiple statements. Let me show an example:

```
public class SendResourceManager : IEnlistmentNotification
{
    private readonly Action onCommit;

    public SendResourceManager(Action onCommit)
    {
        this.onCommit = onCommit;
    }

    public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
    {
        preparingEnlistment.Prepared();
    }

    public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Committing");
        this.onCommit();
        Debug.WriteLine("Committed");
        enlistment.Done();
    }

    public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        enlistment.Done();
    }

    public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        enlistment.Done();
    }
}

public class AsyncTransactionalMessageSender : ISendMessagesAsync
{
    private readonly List<Message> sentMessages = new List<Message>();

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Message> SentMessages
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Message>(this.sentMessages); }
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(Message message)
    {
        if (Transaction.Current != null)
        {
            await Transaction.Current.EnlistVolatileAsync(
                new SendResourceManager(async () => await this.SendInternal(message)), 
                EnlistmentOptions.None);
        }
        else
        {
            await this.SendInternal(message);
        }
    }

    private async Task SendInternal(Message message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Sending");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        this.sentMessages.Add(message);
        Debug.WriteLine("Sent");
    }
}

    [Test]
    public async Task ScopeRollbackAsync_DoesntSend()
    {
        var sender = new AsyncTransactionalMessageSender();
        using (var tx = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            await sender.SendAsync(new Message("First"));
            await sender.SendAsync(new Message("Second"));
            await sender.SendAsync(new Message("Last"));

            // We do not commit the scope
        }

        sender.SentMessages.Should().BeEmpty();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ScopeCompleteAsync_Sends()
    {
        var sender = new AsyncTransactionalMessageSender();
        using (var tx = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            await sender.SendAsync(new Message("First"));
            await sender.SendAsync(new Message("Second"));
            await sender.SendAsync(new Message("Last"));

            tx.Complete();
        }

        sender.SentMessages.Should().HaveCount(3)
            .And.Contain(m => m.Value == "First")
            .And.Contain(m => m.Value == "Second")
            .And.Contain(m => m.Value == "Last");
    }
```

As soon as you introduce a Task.Delay like shown in the example above the generated asynchronous statemachine will never come back and invoke the `this.sentMessages.Add(message)` and `Debug.WriteLine("Sent")`

The problem is I currently see now way to properly enlist asynchronous code inside the enlistment notification. Any ideas how to tackle this challenge?

Comment: Only when you introduce the call to `Task.Delay` you are making an asynchronous call. Before that, everything is synchronous. You are making it asynchronous but without any way to wait for its completion. What is happening and were you expecting to happen? Have a look at the articles on [my async-await general curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).

Comment: Hy paulo, yes I'm aware of that. This was exactly the use case I wanted to achieve. In my case I need to enlist an async send call to the messaging infrastructure inside the enlistment and not send the message if the transaction is not completed. So the task delay simulates the actual asynchronous call.

Comment: You're missing the point, @DanielMarbach. Because you're using an `async void`, there's no way to tell when all the code in `onCommit()` has been executed. So, when you call `enlistment.Done()` the commit code most surely hasn't run. Read the articles on [my async-await curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general) to learn all about how `async-await` works.

Comment: @PauleMorgado Yes I know that. And I wanted to make sure that there is no workaround to this. Because then this makes TransactionScope unusable with async even when you have AsyncFlow enabled.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not awaiting `EnlistVolatileAsync`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I changed that. Was a bug in my code. Nonetheless it doesn't help. Of course when I asynchronously wait inside `ScopeCompleteAsync_Sends` test after the scope complete and dispose the test passes. Changed the sample above

Comment: After reading @PauloMorgado curah content again and thinking about the problem more I'm closing this question. The behavior I see in the code above totally makes sense. Because Completing the scope uses internally the enlistment to asynchrously send the messages the test can only pass after at least 3 seconds (delay I used in the `SendInternal` method. I think it is safe to assume that the third party code I will call can be executed in a short timeframe. I have to be aware that any exception thrown by this code will never be catched!